# How to force mathematica to calculate the integral?

Tags: symbolic

When calculate

```
   temp = Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x] + D[f[x], x], x]
```

Mathematica gives
$$
 \int{({\int f[x]dx}+ f'[x])dx}
$$
instead of
$$
\iint{f[x]dx dx} +f[x]
$$

Therefore, if use

```
   temp /. {f -> (f0 &)} // FullSimplify
```

to replace $f[x]$ by a constant $f0$, a wrong answer will be encountered, i.e., $\frac{x^2f0}{2}$, instead of $(\frac{x^2f0}{2}+f0)$ .

I tried to use 'FullSimplify','Expand' to force the calculation of integral in $temp$, but failed.

What command should I use?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell WL to pull integrals into additions with some pattern matching:

```
temp = Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x] + D[f[x], x], x]

temp //. {int : Integrate[_Plus, ___] :> Thread[int, Plus, 1]}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x] + D[f[x], x], x]

Distribute[temp]
```

$$f(x)+\int (\int f(x) \, dx) \, dx$$